# MySQL Query Quotes and such

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

**Question 1**

Why does this work?

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE x= '".$y."'"
```

but not this?

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE 'x' = '".$y."'"
                                ^ ^
                              Notice the extra single quotes
```

**Question 2**
Is it better to do **id** over **`id`** (with the weird quotes)?
Or is it because that double quotes make it interpret as a variable?

Comment: What that really needs is some [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **never** be inserting user data directly in a query. Use placeholders or there could be severe consequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because the server reads `x` as a value as it is wrap with `single quote`. `backtick` escapes a reserved keyword used within the query, usually it is used to wrap around *columnNames* and *tableNames*.

in your query,

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE 'x' = '$y'
```

`x` there is *not a column* but a string value.

for question 2, you can eliminate those backticks around `id` since it is not a `Reserved Keyword`, here is a full list of reserved keywords in MySQL

- [MySQL Reserved Keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)